# FileReader не видит текстовый файл

Tags: java

Почему мой FileReader не видит текстовый файл?

[image: Почему-то не видит текстовый файл.]

Comment: 1. проверь путь откуда ты считываешь файл, скорее всего из-за того что пытается прочесть в другой директории, попробуй жестко указать путь к файлу

Comment: @ivanK. спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно указать полный путь к файлу txt, у вас там ещё ошибки, надеюсь этот код отражает то, что вы намеревались сделать.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class idea_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:\\file.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        String s  =  " ";
        while (s != null) {
            s = reader.readLine();
            strings.add(s);
        }
        reader.close();
        String[] strings1 = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
        Arrays.sort(strings1,0,strings1.length-1);
        for (String s1 : strings1) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на самом деле ошибка была в указании пути. Когда указал полный путь, все заработало. Спасибо) Но теперь назревает вопрос: "Почему не получается достучаться к файлу через относительный путь?"

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html Обратите внимание на Constructor Detail. Поле fileName - the name of the file to red from. Если вам хочется задать относительный путь, то вам придётся расположить файл в корневом каталоге проекта. 
https://gyazo.com/6df80248bce92738222a241ad019bcf7

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте:

```
import java.io.File:

File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы в показаниях путаетесь....
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
перекомпилируйте проект.

Comment: сделал, но не в этом вопрос. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

У тебя редартор IDEA. файл лежит в папке src перенеси его в папку проекта