# Потоки.InputStream.Java.Как работать с данными

Tags: java, потоки-данных, zip, архивация

Есть архив в нем набор файлов, надо считать файлы из архива и выборочно брать один из них, разархивировать архив на диск не нужно, хотел подгружать отдельные файлы в потоки и потом с ними работать.

Что пробовал:

```
ZipFile zf=new ZipFile("src/pack/text.zip") //загружал архив
Enumeration entries = zf.entries()//собирал список файлов

while(entries.hasMoreElements()) { //проходил по всем элементам архива
    ZipEntry entry=(ZipEntry)entries.nextElement();//брал отдельный файл
    InputStream stream=new InputStream()//создавал поток
    stream=zf.getInputStream(entry);//пихал туда отдельный файл
```

Хотелось бы узнать, что записывается в потоки, только внутреннее файла?

Как дальше пользоваться записанными данными в поток?, т.е. как потом записать например в строку содержимое файла.
 Читал о преобразованиях байтов, мало понятно, надо колдовать с кодировками
Чайник будет рад любой помощи

Comment: У вас слишком много вопросов... Потоки - огромная тема, ее невозможно изложить в рамках ответа на вопрос. Я бы вам рекомендовал начать с освоения класса сканер. Он прост в использовании. Кроме того, почитайте про такой паттерн, как адаптер, потому как использование потоков проявляет свои хорошие качества именно в контексте этого паттерна. Т.е. когда вы создаете поток, принимающий на вход, например, класс файл, потом буферезируете его потом делаете еще что-то, то это и есть адаптер. Такие конструкции похожи на трубы и коллекторы. Вы собираете о, что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вопросов много потому, что когда не понятно, трудно понять с чего начать

Comment: Со сканера. Начинайте с него, потоки вы сразу не освоите. Напишите программу для консольного ввода с клавиатуры. А потом для чтения из текстового файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основные шаги работы с потоками в Java: открыть поток на чтение/запись, прочитать его содержимое или записать нечто в поток, закрыть поток. Для более удобного чтения текстовых файлов [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) с содержимым файла обычно оборачивают в [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) или [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Посмотрите [пример чтения текстового файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463432/17429) на Java.

А вот так можно стандартными средствами Java получить содержимое `InputStream` целиком в виде строки:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

Этот трюк заимствован из статьи ["Stupid Scanner tricks"](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/pat/2004/10/23/stupid-scanner-tricks). Его работа основана на том, что `Scanner` проходит по всему потоку разделяя его на части используя как разделитель "начало границы входного потока" (["beginning of the input boundary"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html), `\A`), т.е. возвращает всё содержимое потока одним куском.

Обратите внимание, что можно указать используемую кодировку входного потока вторым аргументом в конструкторе `Scanner` (например, "UTF-8").

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, одним вопросом меньше)

Comment: @justdoit не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. Из справки: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)